# Simple way to set/unset an individual bit

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Right now I'm using this to set/unset individual bits in a byte:

```
if (bit4Set)
   nbyte |= (1 << 4);
else
   nbyte &= ~(1 << 4);
```

But, can't you do that in a more simple/elegant way? Like setting or unsetting the bit in a single operation?

Note: I understand I can just write a function to do that, I'm just wondering if I won't be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c

Comment: @obelix: So this is how SO was before all the trvial questions were answered already? +112/+241, 90 Favs? Great Question/Great Answer Gold Badge?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure! It would be more obvious if you expanded the `|=` and `&=` in your code, but you can write:

```
nbyte = (nbyte & ~(1<<4)) | (bit4Set<<4);
```

Note that `bit4Set` must be zero or **one** —not any nonzero value— for this to work.

Comment: unset, then set depending on bit4set. Haven't thought of that. Tks.

Comment: `nbyte = (nbyte & ~(1<<4)) | ((!!bit4Set) << 4)` takes care of bit4Set not being zero or one.

Answer (score 12):

Put it in a function, the bool type will enforce 0,1 for all bitval inputs.

```
int change_bit(int val, int num, bool bitval)
{
    return (val & ~(1<<num)) | (bitval << num);
}
```

Comment: if i put it into a function I'd rather use the code I wrote. It is right, nevertheless.

Comment: If you let the compiler inline this function in C++, then it will be as fast as if you had used the expression itself, plus you get the readability-bonus.

Answer (score 8):

This is a perfectly sensible and completely standard idiom.

Comment: It _probably_ introduces branching which can affect the performance. Pascal Cuoq's answer may be less readable, but is more performing.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered assigning mnemonics and/or identifiers to your bits, rather than referring to them by number?

As an example, let's say setting bit 4 initiates a nuclear reactor SCRAM. Instead of referring to it as "bit 4" we'll call it `INITIATE_SCRAM`. Here's how the code for this might look:

```
int const INITIATE_SCRAM = 0x10; // 1 << 4

...

if (initiateScram) {
    nbyte |= INITIATE_SCRAM;
} else {
    nbyte &= ~INITIATE_SCRAM;
}
```

This won't necessarily be any more efficient (after optimization) than your original code, but it's a little clearer, I think, and probably more maintainable.

Comment: that's pretty much the same thing. I'm actually using identifiers, I just didn't put them in the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
nbyte |= (1 << 4);
```

If the right hand side of the assignment, `(1 << 4)`, is always a constant like this, then this would probably be optimized by compiler so it will be simpler in resulting assembly:

```
mov r0, _nbyte
mov r1, 10H         ; here is the optimization, no bit shift occured
or r0, r1
st _nbyte, r0
```

Comment: This is the answer to the question "How do I set bit 4 in nbyte?". The question is "How do I set or unset bit 4 in nbyte depending on the value of bit4Set?"

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood the question. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: I'd give this answer a thumbs up, because even if it is not entirely on point, it adds additional insight, just as Pascal's did.

Answer (score 1):

This is tagged as C++ so have you considered using `std::bitset` instead of doing all the bit manipulation yourself? Then you can just use array notation as: `bits[3] = bit4Set` to set the appropriate bit.